# Use "watch" over ssh

Tags: ssh, terminal, watch

I want to write a script that connects via ssh (`ssh user@host`) and runs `watch who` there.

Normally I would just do

```
ssh user@host
# I am now on the other machine
watch who
```

But a spript would wait until the first command is done and would start the second one. So my next try is

```
ssh user@host watch who
```

but I get an error (`$?` is `1`) and a message:

> "Error opening terminal: unknown"

`ssh user@host who` works just fine though. So how could I approach this?

(My real application is not to watching the users but watching the print queue, but the problem seems to be the same and I guessed that more people are familiear with `who` then with `lpstat`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `watch` needs a PTY, which is not allocated when you add a command to `ssh`. Use

```
ssh -t user@host "watch who"
```

Comment: I already tried that (found it on some related questions), but I get: Error opening terminal: xterm-termite.

Comment: Hmm, It seems to work when I use xterm instead of termite (on my local machine. Any idea why this might be the case?